# Using react props in .map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have the following render function on one of my components.
From the parent element I have passed a `changeTid` prop function.

**Parent:**

```
<RequestsList data={this.state.data} changeTid={this.changeTid} />
```

**Child:**

(I'm using ES6 classes)

```
render() {  
var RequestNodes = this.props.data.map(function(request) {
  return (
    <Request 
        key={request.TID} 
        changeTid={this.props.changeTid}
    />
  );
});

    return (
        <div className="list-group">{RequestNodes}</div>
    );
}
```

I can't use `this.props.changeTid` in my map function as `this` is not referencing what I wan't. Where do I bind it so I can access my `props`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can set `this` for [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Parameters) callback through second argument

```
var RequestNodes = this.props.data.map(function(request) {
   /// ...
}, this);
```

or you can use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which does not have own `this`, and `this` inside it refers to enclosing context

```
var RequestNodes = this.props.data.map((request) => {
       /// ...
});
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're using ES6 you can use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which doesn't bind its own `this`

```
var RequestNodes = this.props.data.map(request => {
  return (
    <Request 
        key={request.TID} 
        changeTid={this.props.changeTid}
    />
  );
});
```