# React Native: map function in return

Tags: reactjs, optimization, native

I just started getting into react native and I was wondering on how to treat map functions within the return.

Based on the answer given here [Using react props in .map function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37155677/using-react-props-in-map-function) I adapted my code as its following:

```
render()
{
    const { active } = this.state

    const drawerContent = Object.keys(drawerItems).map(section => {
        return <DrawerComponent.Section key={section.toLowerCase()} title={section} style={styles.section}>
                {drawerItems[section].map(item =>
                    <DrawerComponent.Item
                        key={item.id}
                        label={item.label}
                        icon={item.icon}
                        style={styles.item}
                        active={active === item.id}
                        onPress={() => nav.push(item.screen + 'Screen', item.props || {})}
                    />
                )}
            </DrawerComponent.Section>
    })

    return(<View style={styles.container}>{drawerContent}</View>)
}
```

Is this the best approach or can anything be better optimized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks good to me. I would consider using [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) instead of `Object.keys`, though.

Comment: Thanks! Challenging though. Different sources suggest different approaches, e.g. this site https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-arrow-functions-and-bind-in-reacts-render-are-problematic-f1c08b060e36 uses the map function within render and specifies an own function inside the class.